# Displaying a boolean as a checkbox within a Webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, checkbox, webgrid

I am trying to use a Webgrid and I can get the data to display but the bool values are where I'm having problems. I would like to just display a checkbox that has the value of my bool. I have been able to get a checkbox within the grid but it is editable and does not show the value correctly.

```
grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table", alternatingRowStyle: "alternate", headerStyle: "header",
columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column(columnName: "string1", header: "String1", format: @<text>@item.string1</text>),
grid.Column(columnName: "bool1", header: "bool1", format: bool1? </text>),
```

If someone has done this before and could shed some light on how to properly display a bool as a checkbox that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this for the bool column:

```
grid.Column(columnName: "bool1", 
    header: "bool1", 
    format: (item) => @Html.Raw("<input type='checkbox' " + ((item.bool1==true) ? "checked" : "") + " disabled='disabled' />")
)
```

Comment: This does show a checkbox but for some reason it does not properly display the value. I have set it like you show, and also tried to hard code true and false as the value but still no change in whether it shows checked or not. Not sure why the value is not working!

Comment: @RicketyBowby ah sorry, my mistake.  The attribute actually needs to be *checked=checked*, not *checked=true*.  Please see my update above.

Comment: yea that'll do it. Thanks also just found this works too format: @<input name="bool1" type="checkbox" value="@item.bool1" @(item.bool1 == true ? "Checked" : null) disabled="disabled" />)

Answer (score 0):

Below is working code for checkbox in mvc5.

```
grid.column("Active", header: "Assign",
  @if (@item.Active){<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"  spellcheck="true"/>}
  else{<input type="checkbox"  spellcheck="true" />} </text>)
```